# GuidedStepFragment edit layout and view attributes and listeners

Tags: android, fragment, textview, android-7.1-nougat, leanback

I pasted a code (simplified to better understanding problem) [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JrGqsz2psm/).

Around line 50-60 (commented code) I wanted to set text of a text view programmatically. But that has no effect. How can I set text for a view in **custom** layout (for guidance part e.g.) ? It seems layout inflation is okay but the code does not give any effect to text of textview!

Thanks